# eclipse: java started but was exited with code=14

Tags: java, eclipse, error-code

I can't open my Eclipse any more and I couldn't find anything related to the exit code 14, only 13.

This is a screenshot of the error window that popped up when I tried to start Eclipse as usual:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: have you installed new eclipse???

Comment: yes i did, was useless, see my own answer, thanks anyways

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okaaaay, its done.

I checked my windows path environment variable. i installed oracle instant client and the installer messed up my path to jre/bin. It installed without telling a jre 1.3, which of course is outdated.

i just set the path back to my jre 1.7 and it worked again

Comment: That's great you got the solution. If you see the screen shot carefully, It says required java version is 1.6

Comment: thats what brought me to the solution, then i thought of the instant client installation(was a msi) and i suggested it might have done something in the background. thats generally the purpose of msi´s and i´m glad i found it. i think i just panicked, have to end my final exams project this weekend ;)

Answer (score 0):

Exit code 14 means the current version of the JVM is incompatible with Eclipse. (Usually you just have to update the JVM.)